# Why isn't my audio element working in HTML5?

Tags: html

I am using the chrome 37 and firefox 31.

When I add the audio tag for chrome. It just doesn't play. There is a cross over the sound control icon

On firefox v31 it just disappears. When I check th w3schools website it works fine. I am using exactly the same code they are using with and doubled check the audio src to make sure its correct but it still doesn't play. Can anyone please help me figure out whats going on??

Below is my code

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="new_simplemenu_order.mp3"  type="audio/mpeg" >

    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: Is anything displayed in Chrome's Console window? Is the .mp3 file being successfully downloaded? Have you tried IE?

Comment: w3schools isn't a good site to learn, see [w3fools](http://w3fools.com). [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) is much better.

Comment: Hey Dai. I checked the console, and actually the source path was incorrect. However for some reason the .wav file is not loading . Its giving me a 304 not modified message..

Comment: Source to the mp3 is mentioned correctly???

Comment: 304 just means that the file has previously been cached by the browser and doesn't need to be downloaded again as it hasn't changed. The server will make this determination based either on ETags (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) or by comparing file size and last modified date. In no way does a 304 response from the server represent a failure to load a resource.

Comment: You make reference to a ".wav" file but there is no such file listed as a source. Is this your complete code?

Comment: @eldan221 Is this still an issue or have you solved your problem?

Comment: pwdst. Thank you for the reply! Yes the issue has been solved!

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem.
It seems to work by if you change your file type to .ogg and also don't use underscores in your file name.
Also, try altering your code to this (credit to [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/371415/html5-audio-play-doesnt-work-on-firefox-chrome)):

```
<audio controls preload="auto">
 <source src="NewSimpleMenuOrder.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>
```

You can hide the controls by doing the following

```
<audio preload="auto">
 <source src="NewSimpleMenuOrder.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>
```

And autoplay by doing this:

```
<audio autoplay>
 <source src="NewSimpleMenuOrder.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>
```

(I hope this fixes your problem!)

Comment: Its a shame this answer isn't marked as accepted. I tried your solution without any other user having confirmed it works, and worked for me, whereas with MP3 files it was not working. For future reference of others, this fixed the problem for me too!